# MongoDB VS MySQL - why mongo/ mongoose creates db and collections automatically?

Tags: mysql, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Coming from the MySQL background, I find MongoDB is a bit odd.

For instance, I have **not** created a database yet, but:

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/kittendb');

var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', function() {
    // we're connected!
    // Start the application after the database connection is ready
    app.listen(3000);
    console.log("Listening on port 3000");
});
```

Result:

```
the kittendb is created // you'll get error in mysql
```

Another one:

I have **not** created a collection in the database yet, but:

```
var kittySchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: String
});
var Kitten = mongoose.model('Kitten', kittySchema);
var fluffy = new Kitten({ name: 'fluffy' });
fluffy.save(function (err, fluffy) {
  if (err) return console.error(err);
});
```

Result:

```
fluffy is inserted into kittens collection! // you'll get an error in mysql
```

mongo console:

```
> show dbs
kittendb    0.203125GB
local   0.078125GB
> use kittendb
switched to db kittendb
> db.kittens.find()
{ "__v" : 0, "_id" : ObjectId("5768e747cf72dd364e7b2fdf"), "name" : "fluffy" }
```

So what is going on with mongo or mongoose? How on earth does it know that to save the kitten into the **kittens collection** which I haven't created!??

What have I missed?

Comment: Mongodb is not mysql.Applying sql experience to nosql db is not fair and will result with unexpected results in many cases. [The docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insert/#create-collection) clearly states collections are created on first insert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How on earth does it know that to save the kitten into the **kittens collection** which I haven't created!??

The naming scheme that Mongoose uses is based on your model names:

```
var Kitten = mongoose.model('Kitten', kittySchema);
```

The model is named *"Kitten"*. By default, Mongoose will lowercase and pluralize that name (so *"Kitten"* becomes *"kittens"*) and use that as collection name.

As for why/how MongoDB creates databases/collections automatically: that's a design decision that the MongoDB creators made. Because databases and collections in MongoDB are schemaless, there isn't a need to have an explicit `CREATE` operation (although to create certain special types of collections, MongoDB does have a [`db.createCollection()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.createCollection/) command).

Comment: Thanks for the answer and great explanation!

Comment: By the way, what is schemaless and schema - what are the differences between them?

Comment: @teelou schemaless basically means that it doesn't require you to create tables, like with SQL, and that documents that are inserted into a collection don't have to be similar.